# How to overwrite a string in a text document

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

Doing a ATM Machine for my computer science project and I wanted to know how to overwrite a specific string of text in a text document.
Ex: The program asks the user how much they want to deposit; program adds deposit amount to total balance.

Fairly new to coding so I know most of the basics (First semester in college) like arrays, structs and StreamReader and StreamWriter so pls no bully for lack of knowledge.

```
RBC002
Ariel Bendahan
1337
50000
```

^ Text file for reference

```
 StreamWriter myfilewrite = new StreamWriter("AccountInfo.txt");
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Write("Entrez le montant à déposer : ");
                    atmFunctions.DepositAmount= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    while (atmFunctions.DepositAmount < 2 || atmFunctions.DepositAmount > 20000)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Entrez le montant à déposer (min $2 max $20,000) : ");
                        atmFunctions.DepositAmount= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    myfilewrite
                    *Stuck here; can't figure out what to put.*

                    DisplayTransaction(bankAccount.AccountNumber,bankAccount.Name,bankAccount.NIP,bankAccount.TotalBalance);
                    break;
            }
```

^ Code segement in which I'm stuck at

Comment: Are you trying to append text without modifying the existing text or are you trying to modify the existing text? If it's the former, you specify that when creating the `StreamWriter`, which you should already know because you should have read [the relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-7.0). If it's the latter then you basically can't. You don't edit text in place. You read the existing text in, modify that text as one or more `strings`, then write all the new text out again.

Comment: How are you stuck? Please provide details on what you expect and what you are getting.

Comment: What is the significance of `RBC002` and `1337`? I am asking this because you need to write a data model class for your bank account and use this class to read/write info as a file.

Comment: BTW: _This is not how banks work_. They do not store account balances, but rather a list of transactions that they sum up to produce the balance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to append a line to your file, then it should be as siimple as:

```
StreamWriter myfilewrite = new StreamWriter("AccountInfo.txt");
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Write("Entrez le montant à déposer : ");
                    var amountToWrite = Console.ReadLine();
                    atmFunctions.DepositAmount= Convert.ToInt32(amountToWrite);
                    while (atmFunctions.DepositAmount < 2 || atmFunctions.DepositAmount > 20000)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Entrez le montant à déposer (min $2 max $20,000) : ");
                        amountToWrite = Console.ReadLine();
                        atmFunctions.DepositAmount= Convert.ToInt32(amountToWrite);
                    }
                    myfilewrite.Write(amountToWrite);

                    DisplayTransaction(bankAccount.AccountNumber,bankAccount.Name,bankAccount.NIP,bankAccount.TotalBalance);
                    break;
            }
```

Just call `.Write()` on your `StreamWriter` and pass it the string you want to append to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by adding the deposit amount to the total balance, then using StreamWriter to re-write the entire file and the new total balance.
I am very sorry if I wasted anyone's time due to me forgetting what my teacher taught me.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the file should reflect the data stored in your program. When a deposit is made, you read the account info from the file (or database), modify the data in memory, and then write the results back.

### Data Model

This is the most basic data model, with some simplistic functionality. It can hold account information and read/write into a single file. This cannot handle multiple accounts from the data file and assumes the data in the file is precisely in the following order.

- Account number (string)
- Account owner name (string)
- Account NIP (integer)
- Account balance (decimal)

if anything is not as expected the program is going to blow up. But it works as intended from the question.

```
public class Account
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int NIP { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public void WriteToFile(string fileName)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
        writer.WriteLine(Number);
        writer.WriteLine(Owner);
        writer.WriteLine(NIP);
        writer.WriteLine(Balance);
        writer.Close();
    }

    public void ReadFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
        Number = reader.ReadLine();
        Owner = reader.ReadLine();
        NIP = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
        Balance = decimal.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

and with a file `AccountInfo.txt` contents

```text
RBC002
Ariel Bendahan
1337
50000
```

I am able to read this information using

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string fileName = "AccountInfo.txt";
    Account account = new Account();
    account.ReadFromFile(fileName);
    // account holds the data from the file
    Console.WriteLine($"Account: {account.Number}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Owner: {account.Owner}");
    Console.WriteLine($"NIP: {account.NIP}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Balance: {account.Balance}");

}
```

### Example Usage

For example, the account data is updated in memory and then written to the file (overwriting the old data).

```
static void Main(string[] args)    
{
    ...

    Console.WriteLine("Enter amount to withdraw:");
    decimal withdraw = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (withdraw >= 2 && withdraw <= 20000)
    {
        account.Balance -= withdraw;
        account.WriteToFile(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine($"Dispensing {withdraw}");
        Thread.Sleep(950);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Withdrawal amoumt must be between 2 and 20,000");
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Balance: {account.Balance}");

    ...

}
```

The key here is the `account.WriteToFile(fileName);` immediately after `account.Balance -= withdraw;`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but now my teacher just updated the project and that it has to be able to store multiple accounts with a max of 200 accounts. I know how to create arrays, the only part that's confusing me is how I can display multiple accounts. Do I have to make it so StreamReader reads every 4 lines or is it something else?

Comment: @Optik - it is up to you to decide on the storage scheme. In my opinion, using a flat file is not a good idea, because if you accidentally delete one line then all data will be corrupt from that point on. I would very quickly find out how to use XML files or some other structured file format. In any case, my posting answers the question of how to write a text file. The next step for you is to create a `Bank` class that stores all the accounts into a `List<Account>` and to write methods for writing and reading the all account data inside this class.

Comment: @Optik - learn about [XmlReader](https://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlreader) and [XmlWriter](https://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter)